# HTML5 video - not setting the current time

Tags: html5-video

This is driving me nuts!

```
video.addEventListener 'ended', (e) =>
    e.target.currentTime = 0
    console.log e.target.currentTime
    # 5.33 seconds NOT 0
```

The video plays, and the ended event is called, but the currentTime is not changed.

Comment: Does changing the currentTime outside of an event callback work? Eg. in the developer console

Comment: Nope, same thing: video.get(0).currentTime = 0
video.get(0).currentTime
5.248000144958496

Comment: well video.load() actually reloads the video at 0 time. So this is a solution i think

Comment: Maybe this could help you as well: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19255990/1525722

Comment: did you find solution for this? In my case its not working if I call it inside a callback

Answer (score 1):

This may be able to help you:

```
video = document.getElementById('video');
begin_play  = 50;
play_video_frist = true; //if you want to run only frist time    
video.addEventListener("play", capture, false);

function capture(event) 
{
     if (event.type == "play") {
         if (play_video_frist) {
             play_video_frist = false;
             video.currentTime = begin_play;
          }
     }
}
```